# AngularJS. ng-include inside of ng-view infinitely loads content of ng-view

Tags: angularjs, ng-view, angularjs-ng-include

this is result of `ng-include` inside of `ng-view` output:

[image: current view of my page]

Of course, I need to load this page only one time.

My app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider

    .when('/first_route', {
        templateUrl: '/templates/first/index.html',
        controller: 'FirstController',
        controllerAs: 'First',
    })
    .when('/second_route', {
        templateUrl: '/templates/second/index.html',
        controller: 'SecondController',
        controllerAs: 'Second',
    });

// I omitted my app.run(), because it contains only headers and redirect to 
// login page for not authenticated users

};
```

In my main `index.html` file I use only `ng-view` directive.

My `first/index.html` contains:

```
<h1>Current page</h1>
<ng-include src="'first/show.html'"></ng-include>
// remaining part of page
```

My `first/show.html` contains:

```
<ng-include src="'second/index.html'"></ng-include>
```

**Resume**: I try to load templates in next order:

1. `index.html` (`ng-view`)
2. `first/index.html`(`ng-include`)
3. `first/show.html`(`ng-include`)

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you rebuild this issue in a small plunker? I can't see anything wrong in the provided code/markup.

Comment: @null I've added my code to plunker and it works fine (http://plnkr.co/edit/XaPLhjQPUBgZZryzFW1U?p=preview). I can't understand, what's wrong with my code on local server, so I continue to debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem.

The issue was in incorrect path, so, when `ng-include` can't find the template, it become infinitely loading itself.

Comment: Saying what the proper path was so future readers can see what your issue was would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

For someone who maybe having similar issue, make sure that `first/index.html` and `first/show.html` contains the content you want to show (not empty page) else you might also have the same loop as above!